# Finding URL is of video or audio in java?

Tags: java

If I give any URL, I want to know whether the URL is `video` URL or `audio` URL.
Is there any API to find ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no "API". A url means nothing. you'd have to actually request the url from the server and examine the response. e.g. do a `HEAD` request and see what the `Content-type` comes back as.

Comment: Could you please provide some snippet if possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function of the Java language.  You might be able to find some third party library that does what you want, but you have not provided enough information to determine what it is you really want in any reasonable set of circumstances.  The following might do what you want, though.

You could just get the ContentType from the http request using something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(myUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
connection.connect();
String contentType = connection.getContentType();
```

A list of common video ContentTypes that you could detect for are [listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video).  You'll see video/avi and video/mpeg listed, for example.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3U22NEHJgU is video url .but content type returns as text/html

Comment: No, that's not a video URL.  If you go to it, it's an HTML page with an embedded video on it. That's why you can put it into your browser and go to the YouTube page.